# MySQL Update column with grouping

Tags: mysql

I have...

```
id      email      groupid
=========================================
1       abc@def    0
2       abc@def    0
3       yyy@yyy    0
4       zzz@zzz    0
5       abc@def    0
6       abc@def    0
```

I want...

```
id      email      groupid
=========================================
1       abc@def    1
2       abc@def    1
3       yyy@yyy    2
4       zzz@zzz    3
5       abc@def    4
6       abc@def    4
```

I'm running this...

```
set @previous_email= 0;
set @row= 0;
update slcms_table a, (select if(@previous_email=email, @row:=@row+1, @row:=1) as row, @previous_email:=email, email from slcms_table order by id) aa set a.groupid = aa.row where a.email=aa.email
```

but this gives to me...

```
id      email      groupid
=========================================
1       abc@def    1
2       abc@def    1
3       yyy@yyy    3
4       zzz@zzz    4
5       abc@def    5
6       abc@def    5
```

How can I do what I want in Mysql? I need to set sequential values to groupid column.

Answer (score 0):

So you're assigning each distinct email a groupid?  If so,  update groupid based on each distinct email: `update tablename set groupid=x where email in (select distinct email from tablename);`.  First just select the distinct email,  which is the nested query inside the update query.  Then create ordinals,  I suggest to use `Select @a:=@a+1 as ordinal` (the value to update groupid) -this site has a good explanation on ordering with mysql: http://www.expattech.com/en/ordinal-row-numbers-in-mysql-queries/40017 -, those aridinals will be the x variable to update groupid.